# CGAffineTransformMakeRotation not working for UILabel Inside UIGraphicsContext

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, transform

My problem is as follows. I am currently drawing UILabels onto a Graphics context (canvas) and positioning them where i please. The graphics context is basically a png image that i am drawing the labels on. This method works perfectly as i don't have to worry about constraints for different labels/ different sized devices etc. Each label will have unique information and i will draw the labels in different spots based on the users choice on how to display said info. But i will be doing this on an image rather than a uiview and when i end the graphics context i use the resulting image in my uiimageview. THIS WORKS PERFECTLY just how i like it. But my problem is, in certain instances i have to rotate a specific label based on which format (background image) for which the chose to display the information. And what i've tried has not worked at all. I'm using Swift and i've tried the following code

```
 title.drawTextInRect(CGRectMake(50.0,230.0,400,200.0))

 title.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity// tried with and without  this line but no change

 title.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_4))
```

I have also tried to do the transform before drawing the label but that does not work either. Can someone please help me with this problem?????

Answer (score 0):

have you tried rotating the context? I had the same problem and this fixed it for me:

`CGContextRotateCTM(context, CGFloat(M_PI_4));`